# Serializing and Deserializing between different crates

Tags: rust, traits, serde

I have two modules crate_old and crate_new:

```
/*
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1"
typetag = "*"
*/

pub mod crate_old {
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    pub struct MyStruct(
        #[serde()]
        pub usize
    );

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    pub struct MyStructAppend(
        pub usize,
        pub usize
    );

    #[typetag::serde(tag = "MyTrait", content = "value")]
    pub trait MyTrait {}

    #[typetag::serde]
    impl MyTrait for MyStruct {}

    #[typetag::serde(tag = "RealStruct", content = "value")]
    pub trait RealStruct {}

    #[typetag::serde]
    impl RealStruct for MyStruct {}

    #[typetag::serde]
    impl RealStruct for MyStructAppend {}
}

pub mod crate_new {
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    pub enum RealStruct {
        MyStruct(usize),
        MyStructAppend(usize, usize),
    }

    #[typetag::serde(tag = "MyTrait", content = "value")]
    pub trait MyTrait {}

    #[typetag::serde]
    impl MyTrait for RealStruct {}
}

fn main() {
    let crate1_box: Box<dyn crate_old::MyTrait> = Box::new(crate_old::MyStruct(10));
    let crate1_box_str = serde_json::to_string(&crate1_box).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(crate1_box_str, r#"{"MyTrait":"MyStruct","value":10}"#);

    let crate2_box: Box<dyn crate_new::MyTrait> = Box::new(crate_new::RealStruct::MyStruct(10));
    let crate2_box_str = serde_json::to_string(&crate2_box).unwrap();
}
```

In each of the modules, there is a type MyStruct. In the old crate, it is a struct, and in the new one it is a enum which has a variant RealStruct, which has the same struct as the MyStruct in crate_old.

I get a serialized object in the crate_old:

```
let crate1_box: Box<dyn crate_old::MyTrait> = Box::new(crate_old::MyStruct(10));
let crate1_box_str = serde_json::to_string(&crate1_box)?;
"{\"MyTrait\":\"MyStruct\",\"value\":10}"
```

In crate_new, I have the following object:

```
let crate2_box: Box<dyn crate_new::MyTrait> = Box::new(crate_new::RealStruct::MyStruct(10));
let crate2_box_str = serde_json::to_string(&crate2_box)?;
"{\"MyTrait\":\"RealStruct\",\"value\":10}"
```

How can I deserialize crate1_box_str to an object the same as crate2_box in crate_new? I thought it may need custom deserialize typetag, but I can't find how. to do it.

Comment: In `crate_new`, are you intending to utilize the dynamicism offered by `typetag` or simply use the enum? If the latter, you can forgo trying to deserialize into boxed traits completely and simply use `RealStruct` directly. [Demo on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce6daceb8660e6924137580d8f1b36ab)

Comment: In `crate_new`, I am intending to utilize the dynamicism offered by `typetag`. So I can not rename the serde name of `RealStruct` to `MyTrait`.